# Adding Tax to Shipping in Opencart

Tags: opencart, checkout, tax

How do you add tax to a shipping amount on Opencart?

I obtain the following checkout summary on my site:

Sub-Total:  £332.50
Delivery Zone 1:    £49.99
VAT (20%):  £66.50
Total:  £448.99

Delivery is £49.99 inclusive of VAT so it needs to read as follows:

Sub-Total:  £332.50
Delivery Zone 1:    £41.66
VAT (20%):  £74.83
Total:  £448.99

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shoud assign a tax class to your shipping mode in **Extensions > Shippings** and put the price of your shipping method without the VAT price included. Make sure you also set a tax class on your product and that **Extensions > Order totals > Taxes is enabled.**

Your checkout summary now will show you the shipping price without the VAT included. You'll find the total VAT price (calculated by adding the VAT of the product's price and that of the shipping cost) in the VAT field.

Comment: Thank you for your swift response, all sorted.